# Angular 6: Cannot find module '@angular/cli/plugins/webpack'

Tags: webpack, angular6

I have updated my project from Angular 5.2 to Angular 6.0 following all steps as mentioned in the [update guide](https://update.angular.io/).
Now, when running npm start, I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@angular/cli/plugins/webpack'
```

The line throwing the error is this import in the webpack.config.js

```
const { GlobCopyWebpackPlugin } = require('@angular/cli/plugins/webpack');
plugins.push(new GlobCopyWebpackPlugin({
    "patterns": [
      "assets",
      "favicon.ico"
    ],
    "globOptions": {
      "cwd": process.cwd() + "/src",
      "dot": true,
      "ignore": "**/.gitkeep"
    }
  }));
```

The imported package no longer exists with CLI 1.6.

Also searching for it, I could not find a solution (update webpack config or replace GlobCopyWebpackPlugin with something else).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went for this solution using the [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/) instead

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

  plugins.push(new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    { from: process.cwd() + '/src/assets/**/*', to: process.cwd() + "/dist", ignore: ['*.gitkeep'] },
    { from: process.cwd() + '/src/favicon.ico', to: process.cwd() + "/dist" }
  ]));
```